# How to call a scope inside a ng-repeat just for the last element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a scope function inside my `ng-repeat` just for the last element, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="patient in patients" >
  <div ng-if="$last" ng-load="myFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

But `ng-load` doesn't work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
  <div ng-repeat="element in array" ng-init="$last && myFunction(element)">
       {{element}}          
  </div>
```

There you have working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8Gcb/).

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-init="$last && myFunction()", that should do the same thing.

Comment: Now the function is called for all the elements.

Comment: @R3tep, makes sense. Throw in the if($last) myFunction(), I changed the answer. And you could probably move this up to the parent div as well.

Comment: @R3tep, Yup go for the poor mans version and use ng-init="$last && myFunction()"